# Formatting in Django models

Tags: python, django, frontend

I am working in django where the I have some models in my model.py file and accordingly data is added by the django-admin and the data is kind of in the type of the **messages we receive in messengers** i.e,

It has some properties like:

1.part of the text is a link.

2.part of the text is in bold/italic.

For formatting the messages like this, is there any way we can implement this or any preexisting Field like this? (Where I can style my text accordingly like the way whatsapp works i.e, it detects the links and gives ability to bold, italicize the text etc...)

Comment: You want to research a bit on WYSIWYG (What you see is what you get) solutions. You might find some suitable packages from this grid: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/

Comment: Thanks a lot @AbdulAzizBarkat I got what I am looking for.

Comment: What @AbdulAzizBarkat said. Or store the message as html then render it in you templates with the safe filter like so: {{message|safe}}

Comment: @EPaul Is it like doing so it preserves the formatting?

Comment: It will be rendered as html, not as text.

Comment: Got it @EPaul I will try it Thankyou.